# Почему при вёрстке стоит использовать классы вместо id

Tags: вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста почему при вёрстке стоит использовать классы вместо id? Серьёзных довод не нагуглил...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [здесь](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2006/01/22/id-class-difference/) хорошо все написано!

> Серьёзных довод*ов не нагуглил...

Бред!

Comment: что именно бред?

Comment: Бред что не нагуглил)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `id` - это уникальный параметр, а классы могут применяться для нескольких элементов.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то Class для группы, ID для одного элемента, на каждой странице может быть один и тот же ID. 
Я не знаю, какие задачи вы будете решать, есть много путей, они просто разные и можно делать, как привык, как нравится, как удобнее.

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю что id параметер на страницу уникален, а классов можно применить сколько угодно и к сколько угодно элементам. Кстати только что мне немного дошло в чём соль. Я думаю просто при использовании классов файл css становиться меньше на больших проектах и легче масштабировать, изменять в дальнейшем такую верстку.

Comment: @Jeremen1: если у вас много однотипных элементов на странице, или хуже того они создаются динамически, class -- гораздо лучшее решение, чем перечисление всех id.

Answer (score 1):

Одно из преимуществ id - элемент с определенным id на странице может быть только один, следовательно не нужно писать кучу дополнительных классов. Можно просто:

```
#block{
  display: block;
}
```

вместо:

```
.wrapper .sidebar .nav .block{
  display: block;
}
```

То есть можно использовать в CSS и JavaScript для быстрого доступа к элементу, если не предполагается создание второго элемента с такими же стилями. Во всех остальных случаях лучше использовать классы.